# Recursive Algorthims In Apex

Tags: apex, recursion, algorithm

This is really just a general CS question. I have been trying to increase my knowledge of algorithms and data structures. And of course, every CS class is full of examples of recursive algorithms. Does anyone ever implement a recursive algorithm in Apex considering that there is a maximum stack depth limit? Or is an iterative algorithm pretty much always the way to go?

I am just curious what the community consensus is.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 7):

Recursion is *probably* acceptable in most use cases where you'd use recursion in Apex, despite the small stack size, as most algorithms will be ultimately limited by either Heap, CPU, or SOQL queries well before you would reach the stack depth limit.

For example, here's a simple [XmlToJson](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2016/01/converting-xml-to-native-objects.html) bit I wrote a while ago. It uses recursion to travel through XML nodes. Since most XML structures won't have 1000 levels of nesting, this design was perfectly acceptable for my use case.

Alternatively, using recursion to calculate Fibonacci numbers or n! might be a bad idea, as you'd be limited to only the first 1000 such numbers. Before deciding to use recursion (or not), consider the maximum possible depth you need to go. If it seems unlikely you'll ever reach that limit, recursion is probably acceptable.

I keep using indefinite terms like "probably", because there's also a CPU factor. Calling methods are relatively expensive compared to using a simple index-based approach, so deeply recursive methods may benefit from not using recursion. Some testing should be applied if you're not sure.

Comment: Have you ever found a need for a Fibonacci sequence in Salesforce development?? Please share! lol

Comment: I have to implement an enterprise Fizz Buzz generator ;)

Comment: @stackasaur I did once write a Fibonacci generator in Apex. I think it was more of a learning experience than a business use, though. As I recall, that was the method that introduced me to the stack limit.

Comment: @BrooksJohnson, I'm not paid enough FooBars for that!

Comment: On that topic, it was my Factorial Calculator that first introduced me to the stack limit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but very rarely.

In Salesforce, I've only needed to use it twice:

1. When using HTTP and converting an XML response to JSON.
2. If you start making really complex systems of assigning users/community users to other objects by things like distance, you can end up recursively calling a method with an increasing distance parameter until you meet the max distance or number of people you need.

You still have to follow the same SOQL limits, so you wouldn't want to call a method on a parent that gets children then the same for each child and so on, as you'd hit limits. So it really just becomes hard to find that many needs for it in Apex, in my opinion.

Also interested to see what others have to say!

Comment: #2 is actually similar to a use case we do use recursion for. We build sharing groups dynamically by role using a regular expression pattern, because roles change frequently in our org and we didn't want to have to have our admins continually make public groups.

Comment: Now, without seeing the details, I'd have said that #2 would be something to simply use a Map<Object[], List<X>> for in an interative implementation.

Comment: I don't want to say too much about the details, but the problem could be modeled as a graph (the edge and node kind) and it became a traversal issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone ever implement a recursive algorithm in Apex considering that there is a maximum stack depth limit?

I had come across this situation couple of years back when I was looking for a solution to display Account hierarhcy on a Visualforce page. In fact, I had utilized [Inline Account Hierarchy](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016chCEAQ) package from Salesforce Labs which has a *recursive* implementation. I would think *recursion* can be still applicable for some use cases and I don't see any issue in implementation provided it's implemented well within the boundaries of the platform as applicable for any other implementation.

For the details on account hierarchy implementation that I did, you can read more on my [blog post here](https://jdspaceit.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/traversing-through-an-accounts-hierarchy-in-apex/).

Comment: great use-case, thanks for sharing. being mindful of governor limits, of course, but this is a classic use-case of recursion... traversal down a tree of depth N with unknown width... definitely well-solved with recursion.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently asked to come up with a solution to this type of scenario: Imagine we are in an org that uses Cases, and there are two custom Decimal fields: Total_Duration__c (Formula Field), and Family_Total_Duration__c on the Case object. Write a method which accepts the Id of the "Parent" Case and calculates the Family_Total_Duration__c  for the "Parent" Case and all of it's children's children's... child cases as the sum of all Total_Duration__c amounts for the Cases below it. This kind of requirement is by definition recursive and the soulution involved something like this:

```
Decimal sum(Map<Id,Case> caseMap, Id currentId, Map<Id,Set<Id>> parentIdToChildIds) {
        decimal sum = caseMap.get(currentId).Total_Duration__c;
        if (parentIdToChildIds.containsKey(currentId)) {
            for (Id i : parentIdToChildIds.get(currentId)) {
                sum += sum(caseMap, i, parentIdToChildIds);
            }
        }
        caseMap.get(currentId).Family_Total_Duration__c = sum;
        return sum;
    }
```

I also have been asked to calculate the modulus of the string representation of a number that is far too large to be stored as a Long. By stripping off the last 8 characters and using the distributive property of modular multiplication, I was able to come up with a recursive solution which was able to perform the operation.